# CSS - Stop table cell background overflowing outside of its width/height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML/CSS:

```
<header>
    <div id="left" class="cell"></div>
    <div id="centre" class="cell"></div>
    <div id="right" class="cell"></div>
</header>

header {
    height: 18%;
    background-color: #0099ff;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.cell {
    display: table-cell;
}

#left {
    width: 20%;
    background: url("../img/3lines.png") no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 25% auto;
}

#centre {
    width: 60%;
    background: url("../img/logo.png") no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}

#right {
    width: 20%;
    background: url("../img/3lines.png") no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 25% auto;
}
```

Images of what's happening, this is what is happening now with a small portrait screen, this is perfect:

[image]

This however is not perfect, when viewed in landscape the logo flows outside of its cell:

[image]

How can I stop the logo from overflowing outside of its table cell?

Comment: Why the JavaScript and jQuery tags?

Comment: @j08691 I'm unsure if what I'm asking can be done with CSS alone

Comment: @RobSedgwich Ah, that answers what I'm asking but then the width becomes the problem: http://i.imgur.com/LH7WYZ6.png

Comment: @RobSedwick Yes but now it's not properly working in portrait

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`background-size: 100% auto;` is stretching your background to fill it's parent horizontally. As the width:height aspect ratio of the element increases beyond that of the background image, the image is forced to grow vertically beyond it's container in order to fill that 100% width.

What you want is just `background-size: contain;`, as that will constrain it to the size of the element and make it as large as possible without stretching it.

```
div{
    background: url("https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png") no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 200px;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DL5LC/1/)

Comment: Thanks, this is a step closer but doesn't fix the problem fully. If I make the window small enough it will still overflow like this: http://i.imgur.com/jJ8JAto.png

Comment: It doesn't fit the table cell at all with just auto, it just stays the same height constantly

Comment: If you are willing to allow the image to be distorted, you could use `100% 100%`. I'm not sure that this is possible using background-images. I can definitely get this to work with an <img> though.

Comment: Ooooh, I hadn't thought about using the <img> element. Could you perhaps add to your answer with a working example? Sadly I cannot distort the image due to requirements.

Comment: Ah! found it! you want `background-size: contain`.

Comment: Oh my god, how have I not seen this before? Thank you so much! Is this a new attribute?

Comment: Not that I know of. My reference is 2 years old.

Comment: Thanks so much, you've just solved over an hour of head scratching :-)